# How do I put a piece of text above another? (Using div)

Tags: html

I am creating a website, but the top of the website with the name and what page you are on is too far spaced out. ATM it looks like this;

```
                                Website Name

                               Page you're on
```

---

But I want there to not be the spaces between. I have tried using div tags to position it but whatever I do they dont move.

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Website name -Home</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: #3399FF;
}

h2 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h4 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

p{
font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-        serif;
}

hr { 
width: 100%
}

#pageTop {
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
right: 0;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}

#titleDivide{
position: relative;
}



</style>
<body>

<div #id="pageTop">
<h2>Website Name</h2>
<h4>Home</h4>
</div>

<div #id="titleDivide">
<hr />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the margin from `h2` and `h4`:

```
h2, h4
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Demo:

```css
body
{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
h2, h4
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
p
{
    font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
}
hr
{ 
    width: 100%
}
#pageTop
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}
#titleDivide
{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Website name -Home</title>
    <body>
        <div #id="pageTop">
            <h2>Website Name</h2>
            <h4>Home</h4>
        </div>
        <div #id="titleDivide">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```